# How to integrate simplesamlphp library and update configuration when composer update in Zend Framework3

Tags: php, zend-framework, simplesamlphp

I installed SIMPLESAMLPHP library with composer using

composer require simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp

For configuration I need to add saml-autoconfig.php file at my SIMPLESAMLPHP library root.But my vendor folder is in .gitignore file.

When I update my composer @production whole configuration with saml-autoconfig.php file gets missing.

I need to configured it when my composer get update.

If anyone have idea.Please help

I need to add following file with configuration

1) In saml-autoconfig.php .

```
$metadata_url_for = array(
    /* WARNING WARNING WARNING
     *   You MUST remove the testing IdP (idp.oktadev.com) from a production system,
     *   as the testing IdP will allow ANYBODY to log in as ANY USER!
     * WARNING WARNING WARNING
     * For testing with http://saml.oktadev.com use the line below:
     */
     // 'test' => 'http://idp.oktadev.com/metadata',
);
```

2)vendor/simplesamlphp/config.php

```
'baseurlpath'=>''
```

3)vendor/simplesamlphpauthsources.php

```
 'default-sp'=>''  //its default one .I want to add more sp.
```

How I add dynamically saml-autoconfig.php this file and set my configuration.

Comment: How to include/use  simplesamlphp library at my controller and create object form library like  $as = new SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple($sp);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute a command after composer finished the install/update process, you can use the `post-install-cmd` and `post-update-cmd` options.

In this case, assuming that the `config` folder contains your configuration, you need to add this in your `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp": "^1.17"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "cp ./config/config.php ./vendor/simplesamlphp/config.php",
            "cp ./config/authsources.php ./vendor/simplesamlphp/authsources.php"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "cp ./config/config.php ./vendor/simplesamlphp/config.php",
            "cp ./config/authsources.php ./vendor/simplesamlphp/authsources.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

I also downloaded the `simplesamlphp` library, and the path you reported doesn't seem right. The correct path to install the configuration files should be `vendor/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/config`

Comment: One more question is that.I added Relay state `localhost:8080/index.php/?saml_sso=example`  In IDP .I am trying to test @local enviornment.Is it possible with port ?

Comment: I've never used this library, so I don't know if it possible or not. It would be better to look at this: https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/issues/337